# Fingerprint scanning repeatedly

Tags: microcontroller, c, embedded, image-sensor

[image]I am using [2](https://www.hfteco.com/product/Thumb-Scanner-Capacitive-Fingerprint-ModuleFingerprint-Module-supplier-manufacture.html) fingerprint module to make an attendance machine.

Normally i have seen the attendance machines just need the user to put his/her finger on the scanner and it is scanned.. then next person put his/her finger and then that finger is scanned.. and so on.. a user is not required to press any button on the machine to start the scanning process. the machine is always in the scanning mode and waiting to detect a finger.

I have seen the command set of the above FP sensor and it works in the polling mode. We have to send a command to start scanning and after successful scanning or timeout it returns. It looks like it cannot do continuous scanning. Or if we need to do continuous scanning then we have to repeatedly send the start-scanning-command over and over again.

I wonder if my understanding is correct or if i am missing something to achieve continuous scanning?

edit:

Adding picture of the available signals on the FP Module.[![enter image description here][![enter image description here][3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AHN9r.jpg)][3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AHN9r.jpg)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm missing a datasheet on that sensor, but here is a hunch:

The sensor is capacitive, meaning, once someone puts the finger on it, it will charge a capacitor on the device.

This makes me think there has to be a way using this capacitor being charged as an interrupt signal for the micro controller. This way you won't have to continuously poll it.

Here on [eBay](https://www.ebay.es/i/273284597914?chn=ps) a capacitive sensor:

[image]

The wakeup signal goes high when a finger is detected.

As for the signals you posted earlier, I have not been able to identify such a signal. Maybe the sensor you are using only supports polling.

**OPTICAL SENSOR FOUND EARLIER**

I made a quick search of some other fingerprint scanner and found [this](https://www.dx.com/es/p/optical-uart-serial-fingerprint-recognition-sensor-module-for-arduino-2072969?tc=EUR&ta=ES&gclid=Cj0KCQiAnY_jBRDdARIsAIEqpJ0A81xoyh3ZSaL69tc1UE0r21vnU2XxADV4D3_kUe2EvFoGmtnegIgaAszFEALw_wcB#.XGQAzlxKhaQ). This one is optical though

By looking at the documentation in this [link](https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0B6uNNXJ2z4CxRjh2VnJ1RzBmTVE&usp=sharing), I see the following signals are available:

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately there is no signal like that in the command set. All the commands are on UART interface. Can you point out any other FP sensor that has an interrupt signal as you mentioned?

Comment: Answer edited with an example, hope it helps :)

Comment: I have edited the question to include picture of available signals on the FP module. Do you see any possible signal that can be used as an interrupt signal?

Comment: BTW your above mentioned FP sensor is Optical sensor unlike a Capacitive sensor. How would it detect for a finger?

Comment: You are right, I left the info on the optical one just for reference and added info on a capacitive one I've found